# How to Split and Copy its values

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner, and am stunned with splitting and copying.

I have a workbook (book1) which contains some student's name in column A and Pay school fee Date in Column B. Some names have more than one date, while some have only one:

A...............B.

Kaka.........10/07/2018

Thy............12/05/2018, 15/08/2018, 15/08/2018

Then I  want to search their name in another workbook and copy its entire row to new workbook. All help is welcome; thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that the second worksheet contains 1 row for **each date** per Student?  Some screenshots of example data from both sheets (and a manually-created example of the expected result?) might help us understand the question better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform operation this way although You had not show Your code but I have written my own code as my understand about code.

```
Sub transferData()
    'Declare an array
    Dim LArray() As String
    'Start For loop
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
        'Check Condition for multiple date exits or not
        If (UBound(Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value, ",")) > 0) Then

            LArray = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value, ",")
            'Split Date and store inside Array
            For j = 0 To UBound(LArray)

                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2 + j) = LArray(j)

            Next j

        Else

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

If You find it helpful then pleasure for me and vote my answer or in case any doubt feel free to ask me.

thanks

Comment: Yes, thank Dheeraj, it is work But it is only about Spit Date, it isn't go to search and copy its entire row yet. Could you see the Noted that I comment under your answer , please? You may get more interested on it. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @MissSeven you want to search by name or what?

Comment: If you use `Split` on a string which does not contain the deliminator, you get a 1-item array - there is no need to check for multiple dates and treat them differently.  You can `Split` the Array once, before your `j` loop, and `For j = 0 To UBound(LArray)` instead of re-splitting every repeat.  Also, why are you using `Cells(i, i + j)` instead of `Cells(i, 2 + j)`?

Comment: @Chronoidal we can also solve in that way as you have discussed and it's my mistake that I have written Cells(i, i+j) instead Of Cells(i, 2+j)

Comment: I want to split and then search name in another workbook , and copy it to one another workbook .